# Neon Tetras what other species would work nicely with them

Tags: fish, compatibility, tetra

I have a *tropical fish tank* at the moment with 2 types of tetras in it:

- Tiger Tetras
- Neon Tetras

and 2 Catfish (not sure of the exact name).

I was wondering what type of fish would work well in a living environment manner. It doesn't have to look nice.

Comment: Welcome to pets.se! I edited your question to add tags and make it look like you intended. Leave a comment if you disagree.